# Kernel gets stuck after sock_release() call in a custom module

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I wrote a Kernel module that deals with socket-based TCP connections. Everything works great except one specific use case. I’d appreciate if somebody advise me how to solve the problem described below.

I have:

1. Kernel module which is a device registered using
   **misc_register**().
2. User space application that communicates with this module using the standard file i/o functions: **open**,
   **close**, **ioctl**, etc.

The exact scenario looks like this:

1. Load the module using insmod.
2. Open the associated device from user application using the standard **open**() function
3. call **ioctl**() that performs the following actions in the Kernel module (insignificant code lines omitted):

`

```
...
sock_create(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sock);
...
flags = O_NONBLOCK;
sock_map_fd(*sock, flags);
...
kernel_connect (sock, (struct sockaddr *)server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), sock->file->f_flags);
...
```

`

All functions return successfully. The TCP connection is established successfully. After that tere can be also reads/writes on this connection but it doesn’t influence the problem.

If the application finishes naturally or I interrupt it by sending SIGINT the connection is closed nicely - with FIN exchange etc. On SIGKILL it issues TCP as I expect. No problems so far.

Now I would like to close this socket w/o stopping application.  I try to do it by calling **sock_release**() in my Kernel module via another ioctl call. Upon this call the TCP connection is also closed nicely. However now the Kernel gets stuck when my application finishes or is interrupted!

I suspect that the Kernel somehow is not “informed” that the socket is closed. It tries to close it again and fails once the socket memory structure is de-allocated.

Did somebody use sockets from Kernel modules and had similar problems?
Can you recommend an alternative way to work with TCP sockets  from Kernel modules?
Alternative ways to close sockets from within Kernel?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Kernel code investigation I found out that in case you map socket to a file using **sock_map_fd**() function it is not enough to call **sock_release**(). This function doesn't release the file descriptor associated wit the socket. In case you really need to map a Kernel socket to a file keep the file descriptor returned by **sock_map_fd**() and use **sys_close**() function to close the socket and clean up the associated file. Note that when the device file descriptor is closed all sockets created in the module and associated with files are also closed automatically.

Alternatively you can just avoid mapping socket to a file descriptor. The socket basic functionality will stay ok even without the mapping. In this case **sock_release**() works perfectly.